# Connections between prime numbers and geometry

Tags: geometry, number-theory, prime-numbers

This might be a little open-ended, but I was wondering: are there any natural connections between geometry and the prime numbers? Put differently, are there any specific topics in either field which might entertain relatively close connections?

**PS:** feel free to interpret the term *natural* in a broad sense; I only included it to avoid answers along the lines of "take [fact about the primes] $\to$ [string of connections between various areas of mathematics] $\to$ [geometry!]"

Comment: Taken from the Wikipedia page, "The only angles of finite order that may be constructed starting with two points are those whose order is either a power of two, or a product of a power of two and a set of distinct Fermat primes".

Comment: Also, see http://www.stanford.edu/group/journal/cgi-bin/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Erickson_NatSci_2005.pdf.

Comment: The probability for *n* natural numbers to be co-prime is $\dfrac1{\zeta(n)}$ , which for even values of $n=2k$ is a function of $\pi^n$. Is this one of the answers you were trying to avoid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Gauss-Wantzel theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss-Wantzel_theorem) on constructible polygons immediately springs to mind. This states that a regular $n$-gon is constructible with a straightedge and compass iff $n$ is the product of a power of $2$ and a collection of distinct [Fermat primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_prime).

The power of $2$ is only there because if you can construct an $n$-gon, you can easily construct a $2n$-gon by constructing an isoceles triangle on each side of the $n$-gon. Doing this repeatedly, you can get a $2^mn$-gon. So really, this is about the nature of Fermat primes.

Comment: I think this is the best example of a purely geometric question that’s answered with arithmetic information.

Comment: One nice extension of this: a regular $n$-gon is constructible using standard origami techniques iff $n$ is the product of a power of 2, a power of 3, and any number of [Pierpont Primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierpont_prime) — those of the form $2^a3^b+1$.

Answer (score 6):

Here’s an example, far from the best, of prime numbers entering into a (relatively) geometric problem. Consider all the points on the unit circle, $X^2+Y^2=1$. Notice that by considering this as the set of complex numbers $a+bi$ of absolute value one, i.e. $a^2+b^2=1$, this has a natural group structure. Explicitly, $(a,b)*(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$.

Now, here’s the question: What are the rational points on the circle? That is, what are the points $(a,b)$ on the circle for which both $a$ and $b$ are rational numbers? Your first interesting case is $(3/5,4/5)$. Of course there’s an answer to this question coming from the classical solution to the problem of finding all Pythagorean Triples. But I want to ask an arithmetic question: What are the possible denominators of all the rational points on the circle?

The answer comes out of looking at the “primes” in the ring of Gaussian Integers, but I’ll cut to the chase: a number will appear as the (common) denominator $D$ of a *rational* pair $(a,b)$ on the unit circle if and only if the only primes dividing $D$ are those of the form $4k+1$. Naturally, I want the rational numbers $a$ and $b$ to be in lowest terms.

Answer (score 6):

How about another  imagery about prime numbers?   A prime number $p = 1 \times  p$ and hence, geometrically it is like a one-dimensional segment. On the other hand, a composite number $c= a \times b$, where $a$ and $b$ are its prime factors, is like a rectangle having an area $c$, with side lengths $a$ and $b$ . So, in general, composite numbers $c$ may be imagined as multi-dimensional rectangular parallelepipeds with  volumes $c= a \times b \times c \times d \cdots$, having side lengths corresponding to their prime factors. Of course, the question that is pertinent is: does this imagery lead to interesting  results or insights?

Comment: I love this imagery! Not sure where those downvotes are coming from.

Comment: @goblin   Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

A simple example: number p>2 is prime iff any equiangular p-gon with rational side lengths is regular, see, e.g., http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Outline/Geometry/EquiangularP-gon.shtml

Answer (score 3):

Well, prime numbers are strongly related to the Riemann zeta function, $\zeta(s)$. This has a product representation which involves the roots of the function. The Riemann Hypothesis now states that all non-trivial roots in the complex plane lie on the "critical line":
$$Re(z)=\frac12$$
which can be thought of as a geometric feature.

Answer (score 2):

[Events on the horizon of a 2D Universe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0g7j.png)

You may have a look to the graph; it represents all the numbers (red, up to 100) that "see" straight to the origin.
e.g. prime 7 is represented by the seventh vertical point-column, prime 13 by the 13th column. The uniqueness of prime numbers is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Construction of polygons that have prime number properties are more complex to construct than composite numbers, a polygon with composite properties can easily constructed by splitting each compostite fraction into half,
 example, circle in half = 2
Circle in quarters = 4
Continue Quarters in half = 8 (notice 6 is missing in this sequance) because a circle is devided into six by its own radius example would be sacred geometry (creating flower of life)

Here is my layout of prime numbers...
01 03 05 07 11 13 17 19... 02 06 10 14... 04 09 15... 08 12 20... 16 18...

Notice the 1st numbers going across are prime
Notice the 1st numbers going down are composite and are easy to use when constructin pygons (polygons related to geometry) search polygon for further understanding.

Iv noticed prime numbers are never a even number, though i have not studied further on this, only up to 20 that i studied.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, there are several geometrical models for primes (some already mentioned above), that connect algebraic deductions to geometric representations:
1. The Sieve of Eratosthenes, usually depicted on a grid of $10x \times 10y$, but can be made cylindrical if columns are set at $ \tan^{−1} 1/n $ to rows.
2. Ulam Spiral and its variations: Krauber’s triangle, Robert Sack’s number spiral, the hexagonal cloth.
3. Omar E. Pol's prime number diagram.
4. Yuri Matiyasevich and Boris Stechkin's nomogram (a parabola sieve).
5. Gauss-Wantzel theorem (works for Fermat's primes).
6. Models of rectangular shapes in n dimensions. E.g. if n is prime, one cannot build a rectangle with sides a and b so that a and/or b is not 1.

Answer (score -2):

Let there be an infinite triangular lattice.  Sequentially enumerate the triangles in a constant direction and a 6 cell hexagon forms.  However, if one enumerates the cells such that each time a prime number is encountered the direction of fill switches, the number line exits the 6 cell, but forms a new hexagon (24 cells) - confining all natural numbers to infinity.  The reason for confinement is all primes (aside from 2 and 3)are 1Mod6 or 5Mod6 and get stuck in the middle of the 24 cell.
If you are interested in more details, see my woefully outdated website:  hexspin.com